# Outputting YAML with Python: incorrect formatting without lists in input

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm trying to create YAML from Python dictionaries. So far I've tried both PyYAML and ruamel.yaml and both have the same result: if the input dictionary does not contain a list, the output is not formatted correctly.

Here's the script:

```
from ruamel import yaml
import sys

yaml.dump({'name': 'Enterprise', 'class': 'Galaxy', 'armament': ['photon torpedoes','phasers'], 'number': 1701}, sys.stdout)
print('\n')
yaml.dump({'name': 'Enterprise', 'class': 'Galaxy', 'number': 1701}, sys.stdout)
```

And here's the output:

```
armament: [photon torpedoes, phasers]
class: Galaxy
name: Enterprise
number: 1701

{class: Galaxy, name: Enterprise, number: 1701}
```

The desired output is that the second YAML dump should be formatted like the first. What's going on here?

Comment: Are you sure that is the output from you script? The `print('\n')` would actually put **two** newlines between the YAML dumps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old style API and that defaults to output *any leaf
nodes in flow style*. In your case both the list/sequece `[photon torpedoes, phasers]` and your seconds dump (where the root level *is*
the leaf node).

---

Assuming that you don't just want the explanation why this happens, but also how to change this behaviour, with the new API, using instances of `ruamel.yaml.YAML`, the default is to make everything flow-style, including all leaf nodes:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import sys

yaml = YAML()

yaml.dump({'name': 'Enterprise', 'class': 'Galaxy', 'armament': ['photon torpedoes','phasers'], 'number': 1701}, sys.stdout)
print()
yaml.dump({'name': 'Enterprise', 'class': 'Galaxy', 'number': 1701}, sys.stdout)
```

giving:

```
name: Enterprise
class: Galaxy
armament:
- photon torpedoes
- phasers
number: 1701

name: Enterprise
class: Galaxy
number: 1701
```

Still not what you want :-)

You now have two options to get what you indicated: leaf node flow-style on your first dump and leaf node block-style on your second.

The first is to have one instance the `default_flow_style` set used for the first dump and
the "normal" one for the second dump:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import sys

yaml = YAML()

yaml.default_flow_style = None
yaml.dump({'name': 'Enterprise', 'class': 'Galaxy', 'armament': ['photon torpedoes','phasers'], 'number': 1701}, sys.stdout)
print()
yaml = YAML()
yaml.dump({'name': 'Enterprise', 'class': 'Galaxy', 'number': 1701}, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
name: Enterprise
class: Galaxy
armament: [photon torpedoes, phasers]
number: 1701

name: Enterprise
class: Galaxy
number: 1701
```

The second option is to explicitly set the flow-style on the object
that you want to output as sequence.  Therefor you have to created a
`ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq` instance, which is normally used
when loading to preserve flow/block-style, comments, etc.:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, comments
import sys

yaml = YAML()

armaments = comments.CommentedSeq(['photon torpedoes','phasers'])
armaments.fa.set_flow_style()
yaml.dump({'name': 'Enterprise', 'class': 'Galaxy', 'armament': armaments, 'number': 1701}, sys.stdout)
print()
yaml.dump({'name': 'Enterprise', 'class': 'Galaxy', 'number': 1701}, sys.stdout)
```

which also gives:

```
name: Enterprise
class: Galaxy
armament: [photon torpedoes, phasers]
number: 1701

name: Enterprise
class: Galaxy
number: 1701
```

This second option of course gives you fine control (there is also a `CommentedMap`) as you
can have those objects at all levels of your data hierarchy, not just at the leaves that are collections.

---

Please note that you don't have to go through any of these antics when loading the required output from a YAML file that has the formatting as you do want it. In that case the dict resp. list like instances are created with the right flow/block-style, so the output doesn't unexpectedly change when just changing/adding a value and dumping back.